# Create a new file in ftp using powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, ftp, powershell-3.0, ftp-client

I need to upload a file to ftp and following is what I am trying

```
# Config
$Username = "XXX"
$Password = "XXX"
$LocalFile = "E:\shell\File1.xml"
$RemoteFile = "ftp://XXX/Folder1/File1.xml"

# Create a FTPWebRequest 
$FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($RemoteFile) 
$FTPRequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,$Password) 
$FTPRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile 
$FTPRequest.UseBinary = $true 
$FTPRequest.KeepAlive = $false
# Send the ftp request
$FTPResponse = $FTPRequest.GetResponse() 
# Get a download stream from the server response 
$ResponseStream = $FTPResponse.GetResponseStream() 
# Create the target file on the local system and the download buffer 
$LocalFileFile = New-Object IO.FileStream ($LocalFile,[IO.FileMode]::Create) 
 [byte[]]$ReadBuffer = New-Object byte[] 1024 
# Loop through the download 
do { 
    $ReadLength = $ResponseStream.Read($ReadBuffer,0,1024) 
    $LocalFileFile.Write($ReadBuffer,0,$ReadLength) 
} 
while ($ReadLength -ne 0)
```

Now I am getting an error stating

```
Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
```

I have not created any file in ftp by default. I want teh script to create a new file from the local file contents.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use the PowerShell FTP Client Module available here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb

Comment: @DavidBrabant : I need to invoke a PS1 script from my c# code. I am not sure if this will be suitable for it.

Comment: The exception means exactly that, it can't find ftp://XXX/Folder1/File1.xml. Have you verified the file exists on the FTP server?